# Use Mongoose schema with my own connection (Mongo Client)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've organized my server with an entry point like the following:

```
/** index.js
* Here I inject the connection to the Data Access Models (DAO), 
* These are the classes that control the queries to MongoDB.
*/

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000

MongoClient.connect(
  { 
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    poolSize: 50,
    wtimeout: 2500,
 },
)

 .catch(err => {
    console.error(err.stack)
    process.exit(1)
  })
  .then(async client => {
    await ProductsDAO.injectDB(client)
    await ServicesDAO.injectDB(client)
    app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`listening on port ${port}`)
    })
  })
```

But now I need to add some Schema Models to support the insert and update operations. So I'm using mongoose schema like this

```
let Products = mongoose.model('Products', productsSchema);
```

But to effectively use the schema, mongoose expects a connection established like this:

```
//Setup database connection with mongoose
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb';
const connect = mongoose.connect(url);
connect.then((db) => {
  console.log('Connected to database'); 
}, (err) => {console.log(err); });
```

How can I avoid establish a connection through mongoose, to use the already created connection with MongoClient, and still be able to use mongoose schema?